# Set selectedValue in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, combobox

I have two tables: columns and tables (foreign key - Table_ID). I want to show columns in dataGridView with combobox. In combobox to be displayed related table (name tables) and selected item be value that set in columns.

```
List<columns> columns = DataLoader.GetColumns();
List<tables> tables = DataLoader.GetTables();

this.editingDataGridView.DataSource = columns; // my dataGridView
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboBoxColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

comboBoxColumn.DisplayMember = "Table_Name";
comboBoxColumn.ValueMember = "Table_ID";
comboBoxColumn.DataSource = tables;

//add combobox column in dataGrid
this.editingDataGridView.Columns.Add(comboBoxColumn);

//AND this i want set value
int index = this.editingDataGridView.Columns.IndexOf(comboBoxColumn);
for (int i = 0; i < columns.Count; i++)
{
   this.editingDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[index].Value = columns[i].Table_ID;
}
```

After run, I get gridView with combobox column with dataSource, but without selected default value!
[image]

Comment: The selected value depends on the current row of the underlying datasource. What is the default value you want?

Comment: That containde in List columns on field Table_ID. I do it after adding combobxColumn in loop(for each comboboCell i set Value from columns list)

Comment: @KingKing example, in object columns i have field Table_id = 1, after loading datasource into combobox i want that selected value equal 1!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key poin is

```
comboBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Table_ID";
```

Need to set DataPropertyName of dataGridComboBoxColumn

[More this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In vb.net, I found this solution

```
Dim cbx As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = dgvEstudios.Rows(x).Cells(1)
cbx.Value = Trim("String value")
```